# go - open file no such file or directory

Tags: html, file, go, render, template-engine

I write a wrapper function to render template like this

```
func RenderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, data interface{}, tmpl... string) {
    cwd, _ := os.Getwd()
    for _ , file := range tmpl{
        file = filepath.Join(cwd,"./view/"+file+".html")
    }
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl...)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    err = t.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

I setup static folder and route handler in `main`

```
http.Handle("/public/",http.StripPrefix("/public/",http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))))

http.HandleFunc("/",route.IndexHandler)
```

And this is my route handler

```
func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    files:=[]string{"base","index"}
    util.RenderTemplate(w, nil, files...)
}
```

I intend to use template nesting to help `index.html` extend `base.html`

This is `base.html`

```
{{define "base"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charget="utf-8">
    <title>{{template "title".}}</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    {{template "index".}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

This is `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{{define "title"}}Homepage{{end}}
<body>
    {{define "index"}}
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="left">
                    <img src="../public/images/img_landing_page_mac.png">
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <h2 style="font-size: 33px; letter-spacing: 5px">Organize <br>Modern Knowledge<br> for Mankind</h2>
                    <p style="font-size: 20px;margin-top: 35px;letter-spacing: 4px">Consume, Colect and Revisit <br>Knowledge at Your Fingertips</p>
                    <a href="#" style="margin-top: 80px;display: inline-block;margin-left: -17px"><img src="../public/images/btn_get_chrome.png"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    {{end}}
</body>
</html>
```

But when I run server, and request the path on browser, it displays an error

`open base: no such file or directory`

Something's wrong with my rendering function?

Comment: You **really** should handle all error. And I cannot see what is unclear about the error: The cause seems pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl...)
```

I guess `tmpl' seems not a filepath :(
I guess you wanna like this.

```
files := make([]string, len(tmpl))
for i, file := range tmpl{
    files[i] = appendfilepath.Join(cwd,"./view/"+file+".html")
}
t, err := template.ParseFiles(files...)
```

Comment: `appendfilepath`? Do you mean `filepath`?

Comment: It doesn't display any error, it renders nothing at all :(

Comment: wow, sorry...

`files[i] = filepath.Join(cwd,"./view/"+file+".html")`